# RegEx cannot extract parameter

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

have a URL in the following format: http://website.com/item/1

This is my rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

When I try to get the id with $_GET['id'] and then echo it I get nothing.

What causes this?

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home index.php  [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard dashboard.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^register register.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^login login.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^customize customize.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^shop shop.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^settings settings.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)$ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

On the page, I get the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in /www/greendaddy.pw/myavatar/root/item.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/greendaddy.pw/myavatar/root/item.php:13) in /www/greendaddy.pw/myavatar/root/item.php on line 23
```

I believe the second error is caused by the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening due to use enabling of option `MultiViews`. Turn it off by placing this line before your rules. Also you need to use anchors `^` and `$` in your patterns:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^home/?$ index.php  [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^dashboard/?$ dashboard.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^register/?$ register.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ login.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^customize/?$ customize.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^shop/?$ shop.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^settings/?$ settings.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)$ item.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```